# dynamic change of style on form condition via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to set up a change of style via jquery on the condition that form entry is right
Can't really make it work. 
here is a fiddle

```
<div id="protectimages">
Image Library Password
<input class="libaccess" type="password" name="pwd"></input>
<a class="libenter"  href="#">enter</a>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("libenter").click(function(){

 if ( $(".libaccess").val() != test ) {
    $(".protectimages").css('background-color','f6f6f6');
}

});
});
```

Where is my mistake?

edited by all the comments bellow. Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/soloveich/LvXb2/2/

Comment: `"libenter"` -> `".libenter"`, `'f6f6f6'` -> `'#f6f6f6'`, and probably `test` -> `"test"`. But I have to also say I hope you're not planning on using client-side password validation. Anyone can view the source of the page and find the password, or bypass the validation altogether.

Comment: Ah, and `.protectimages` -> `#protectimages`. http://jsfiddle.net/e64Ls/. I would take a look through http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: @user3353748 I removed my Answer, I think your question is incomplete, I cant Assume What do you want with else condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
  put this code in your <head> :-
  <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".libenter").click(function(){

     if ( $(".libaccess").val() != "test" ) {
       $("#protectimages").css('background-color','#f6f6f6');
     }

   });
 });
 </script>
 </head>

 You missed to call the click event by class ".libenter". One more thing "test" should be in string form.
```

Also use id of the div "#protectimages". You have not provided the reference of jQuery library. Without using jQuery library you can not use $.

Answer (score 0):

According to your last edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/soloveich/LvXb2/2/, I answered

Change `$(".protectimages")` to `$("#protectimages")`

and

`if ($(".libaccess").val() != test) {` to `if ($(".libaccess").val() != 'test') {`

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".libenter").click(function () {

        if ($(".libaccess").val() != 'test') {
            $("#protectimages").css('background-color', '#f6f6f6');
        }

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/LvXb2/4/

**Note:** Add jquery in your fiddle